# JavaScript: control logic for Ajax call before form submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML multipart form, with name, email and file upload.

I want to register the user with Ajax first of all. If registration succeeds, I want to then proceed to submit the form. If it fails, I want to avoid submitting the form.

This is my code:

```
  --- HTML ---
   <form id="account-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-ajax="false" action="upload.php" >
   <input type="text" name="username" id="username" /> 
   <input type="email" name="email" id="email" /> 
   <input type="file" id="mediaupload" name="mediaupload" accept="image/*" />
   </form>
  --- JavaScript ---
  accountform.submit(function(event) {
    var registration_ok = true;
    // See if we can register the user
    // And if we can, submit the form. 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/usercreate.php",
        data: postdata,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
           // fine to submit the form. 
        },
        error: function (data){
            // If this fails, we don't want to submit the form!   
            registration_ok = false;
        }
    });
    return registration_ok;
  });
```

However, it's always returning true - I guess this is because the main function returns *before* the Ajax error is called.

How can I prevent it from returning true, and submitting the form, when registration fails?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return false always, instead of `registation_ok`, and then in the success function, go:

```
document.forms["account-form"].submit(); //edited
```

i.e. never submit the form when you press the submit button, wait for the AJAX to return, and then only submit the form if the registration was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just submit the form programmatically in the onSuccess handler  in  your .ajax statement?

Something like this:

```
document.forms["account-form"].submit();
```

Comment: I had that initially, and it kept calling the `accountform.submit` function over and over again. But I see from @Ord's answer that I should have had `return false` as default.

Comment: Don't use accountform.submit().  Instead, just make a button that calls a javascript function that does the same functionality.  Alternately, you could have a nested .ajax call in the outer's onSuccess and post the data with a tokenizer.   Either one should work.

Answer (score 0):

you can make syncronic ajax call, just add the async: false, parameter

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I misunderstood the question.  inside of your success method trigger the form.submit();

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the AJAX call is asynchronous, so the `success` and `error` functions won't be called until after the function has returned the `registration_ok` value (which you pre-set to `true`).

Comment: Yes, indeed, that is the problem :)